# Display appearing after first onclick but then display remains when it should disappear

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick, display

I am attempting to have a dropdown and text appear and disappear depending on the status of a chekbox. If the checkbox is clicked I want the label and dropdown to appear, and disappear when it is unchecked. The elements begin not visible, and after I check the cheeckbox the elements appear, however, when I uncheck the chekbox, the elements do not go away.

I tried using the onclick property that calls a function that depending on the status of the checkbox changes the properties of the two elements. However, it only does something on the first click.

this is the html code:

```
<div class="formItem">
    <label>Affect Commission Cost</label>
    <form:checkbox path="affectCommissions" id="affectCommissions" onchange="toggleCommissionItems()"/>
    <label id="commissionItemTypeLabel" style="display: none">Commission Item Type</label>
    <form:select path="commissionItemType" id="commissionItem" cssStyle="display: none">
        <form:options items="${commissionItems}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="code"></form:options>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

this is the function that is called:

```
function toggleCommissionItems(){
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("affectCommissions");
  var item = document.getElementById("commissionItem");
  var label = document.getElementById("commissionItemTypeLabel");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    item.style.display = "inline";
    label.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    item.style.display = "none";
    label.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

It should always toggle whether the elements appear on the page, however it only works on the first try.

Comment: try adding `console.log(checkBox.checked)` somewhere in there to verify that checked is changing to false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is a working version of what you were looking for. I believe there might have been an issue with the way that the tags were named ie. `form:checkbox` and the style attributes in the tags.

```js
function toggleCommissionItems() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("affectCommissions");
  var item = document.getElementById("commissionItem");
  var label = document.getElementById("commissionItemTypeLabel");

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    label.style.display = "inline";
    item.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    label.style.display = "none";
    item.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="formItem">
  <label>Affect Commission Cost</label>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" path="affectCommissions" id="affectCommissions" onchange="toggleCommissionItems()" />
    <label id="commissionItemTypeLabel" style="display:none">Commission Item Type</label>
    <select path="commissionItemType" id="commissionItem" style="display:none">
      <options items="${commissionItems}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="code"></options>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```